# Rust: why does borrowing a reference inside struct borrow the whole struct?

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

I have the following code:

```
struct MyStruct<'a>{
    data: &'a str,
}

fn get<'a>(S: &'a MyStruct<'a>) -> &'a str{
    S.data
}

fn set<'a>(S: &'a mut MyStruct<'a>, x: &'a str){
    S.data = x;
}

fn main(){
    let mut S = MyStruct{data: "hello"};
    let foo: &str = get(&S);
    set(&mut S, "goodbye");
    dbg!(foo);
}
```

This fails to compile because `let bar: &str = get(&S)` takes an immutable borrow of S, and on the next line we take a mutable borrow. But we didn't borrow the whole Struct S, just the reference inside the struct. Why is the borrow still active?

I think it has something to do with the lifetime annotations in get and set. Those functions are my attempt to "desugar" how the corresponding member functions would look like. If I change the signature of `get` to `fn get<'a, 'b>(S: &'a MyStruct<'b>) -> &'b str`, the code compiles. Why does the signature affect the duration of the borrow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By specifying the lifetime in `get()` to be `fn(&'a MyStruct<'a>) -> &'a str`, you say you're borrowing the whole struct for the lifetime of the string. Because the string is used after the `set()`, that time period includes the `set()`. Thus, during the `set()` the struct is borrowed, which is an error.

If, on the other hand, you specify it to be `fn(&'b MyStruct<'a>) -> &'a str`, you borrow the struct only for the `get()`, and return the string inside with a different lifetime.